# How can I trigger xcode simulator menu bar actions by XCTest?

Tags: ios-simulator, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, touch-id

I want to write some test cases that should by-pass the "Touch ID". I can enable simulator as Touch-ID enabled device by tapping

> Hardware->Touch ID->Toggle Enrolled State

in simulators menu bar.

Can I do this action from XCTest programmatically?

So that I can able to do test cases that are related with Touch ID.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555625

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to automate touch ID or face ID using xcuitest in simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555625/is-it-possible-to-automate-touch-id-or-face-id-using-xcuitest-in-simulator)