# Is it possible to automate touch ID or face ID using xcuitest in simulator?

Tags: ios, xcuitest

Is there a way to automate face ID or Touch ID using xcuitest framework in simulator. Manually I can perform enrolling face/touch id and perform matching or non-matching scenarios. However I would like to know if it can be automated?

Comment: Here is the link. Explore it and you will get your answers. https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/commands/device/simulator/toggle-touch-id-enrollment/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats what i was looking as well but for XCUITest. I had a look but couldn't found anything. Any direction or help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given [this post](https://medium.com/kinandcartacreated/so-you-want-to-automate-ios-biometrics-81bd015f5d38) by Kane Cheshire it is possible to automate touch ID and face ID for unit testing by sending a Darwin notification like so :

```
+ (void)enrolled {
  int token;
  notify_register_check("com.apple.BiometricKit.enrollmentChanged", &token);
  notify_set_state(token, 1);
  notify_post("com.apple.BiometricKit.enrollmentChanged");
}
```

Only in Objective-C though, so you may need to use a bridging header.

Import the files [`Biometrics.m`](https://github.com/KaneCheshire/BiometricAutomationDemo/blob/master/BiometricsAutomationDemoUITests/Biometrics.m) and [`Biometrics.h`](https://github.com/KaneCheshire/BiometricAutomationDemo/blob/master/BiometricsAutomationDemoUITests/Biometrics.h) from his [demo](https://github.com/KaneCheshire/BiometricAutomationDemo) on Gitub and you will be able to call `Biometrics.enrolled()` from your `XCTestCase`.

Comment: According to https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/26, it should be possible to simulate a match with `notify_post("com.apple.BiometricKit_Sim.fingerTouch.match")` and a non-match with `notify_post("com.apple.BiometricKit_Sim.fingerTouch.nomatch")`.

Comment: Yes, that is used in the lib I linked ;)

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot Axel for direction. This post looks really impressive.

Comment: Link in post is broken

Comment: Found it here: https://medium.com/kinandcartacreated/so-you-want-to-automate-ios-biometrics-81bd015f5d38

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if the Touch/FaceId is blocking your XCUITesting, I suggest, you put a simple check like the below to disable the Touch/faceId

```
guard CommandLine.isRunningUITests else {
    return true
}
```

```
extension CommandLine {
    static var isRunningUITests:Bool {
        return CommandLine.arguments.contains("--uitesting")
    }
}
```

You can easily pass `LaunchArguments` like below

```
XCUIApplication().launchArguments.append("--uitesting")
```